# Apache on Win2003 cannot find the path specified

Tags: windows, filepath, apache2.2

A fresh installation of Apache 2.2 on Win2003.
Configuration validates with the apache tool yet when I attempt to access the site the browser displays an internal error.

Apache log shows:

> [Mon Jul 16 13:36:38 2012] [error] [client 10.162.9.158] (OS 3)The
>   system cannot find the path specified.  : couldn't spawn child
>   process: D:/Heatmap/Webapp/public/dispatch.cg

The file system shows:

> D:\Heatmap\Webapp\public>dir dispatch*  Volume in drive D is DATA 
>   Volume Serial Number is C482-3950
>
> Directory of D:\Heatmap\Webapp\public
>
> 05/02/2012  10:56 AM               445 dispatch.cgi 05/02/2012  10:56
>   AM               520 dispatch.fcgi
>                  2 File(s)            965 bytes
>                  0 Dir(s)   5,625,618,432 bytes free

Since I noramlly run Apache on Linux servers I'm stymied as to what the root cause is here.   The system cannot find a path that is present.

Cluestick please.

Answer (score 0):

The bit of the message *couldn't spawn child process* caught my attention.

Research showed the shebang line is actually used by Apache - unless Perl at the WinOS level which associates the file extension with the interpreter - and I needed to correct it in my .cgi.

Specifying the full path to Perl in the cgi's shebang line corrected the problem.